# Looking for a concise way to add title information to each page in Spring MVC via the Controller's Model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `<TITLE>` tag in my JSPs that is set using a value from the request handler:

```
<title><c:out value="${title}"/></title>
```

I created a method to do this to try to avoid adding mess to the Controller logic with this extra information.

But I'm still not happy with the way this looks in the code (My actual controller methods are much longer than the examples provided here so I'm trying to minimize and simplify them as much as possible).

Is there a more consise way of adding this information from within the Controller? (It can't be added in the JSPs).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String foo(final ModelMap model) {
    addTitle(model, "Desolation Row is the title of this page");
    return "foo";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/goo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String goo(final ModelMap model) {
    addTitle(model, "Leopardskin Pillbox Hat is the title of this page");
    return "goo";
}

public ModelMap addTitle(ModelMap model, String title) {
    model.addAttribute("title", title);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: `<title>${title}</title>` does exactly the same thing as `<title><c:out value="${title}"/></title>` in your JSP.  Sorry though, I have no answer to your real question.

Comment: It's not at all the same, c:out escapes html by default

Answer (score 1):

If you want to factor out the addTitle method from your controllers, maybe you can put them in a HandlerInterceptor implementation?

Something like this maybe:

```
public class TitleInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
           String requestUrl = (String)request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE); 
           String title = "";
           if ("/url1.htm".equals(requestUrl)) {
              title = "Title 1";
           } else if ("/url2.htm".equals(requestUrl)) {
              title = "Title 2";
           }
           modelAndView.getModel().put("title", title)
        }

}
```

If you need some processing to determine the title, maybe the modelAndView available to the interceptor will contain the data that will help in determining the title given the url. If no processing is needed, just a simple mapping of a title to a url, you can even implement it as configurable Map during bean configuration in your applicationContext.xml

Some links I found helpful in implementing HandlerInterceptor can be found here:
http://whitesboard.blogspot.com/2009/10/handlerinterceptors-in-spring-web-mvc.html
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go down the `Interceptor` or `Aspect` road (keeping everything in the Controller):

- Create a `BaseController` that all Controllers `extend`
- Have a `HashMap` in the `BaseController` mapping URLs to Titles
- Put the `addTitle` method there too, modifying to return the same string as the JSP name.

`BaseController` code:

```
public ModelMap addTitle(ModelMap model, String page) {
   model.addAttribute("title", titleMap.get(page));
   return page;
}
```

Controller code becomes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/goo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String goo(final ModelMap model) {
   return super.addTitle(model, "goo");
}
```