# Set browser tab title/name in Java Spring Controller response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, http-headers

Is it possible to set specific browser tab's name/title to specific one using just HttpHeaders or other reponse attribute from Java Spring Controller?

Right now my reponse is just a body as image and in browser's tab I can see my methods name, pic's type and resolution (however, I did not set it like that anywhere).

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide some code? What data do you get from your controller method?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can just add a variable in the controller method.

Than you need to generate html code of your page, where will be your image and data.

Result file will be something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>*Your custom title from @PathVariable or @RequestParam from your method*</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src=...>
</body>
</html>
```

You create a service method that is called in your controller. Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pV0v_3YRQoM) to a tutorial where the html file is created if we do not add any third-party libraries. And in the line that will be converted to the html file, you will write your title by concatenation.

Like that:

`String htmlFile = '... <title>' + fileName+ '</title> ...';`

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work for your case.

Comment: Let’s say I have a @RequestParam in my Controller, „fileName”. How do I call this data in <title>?

Comment: I updated the answer, I think you can try this. Please reply if it'll works @Nevras

Comment: Well, this is not quite my case, I guess. Let me explain my code on another words. I have a Spring Controller with endpoint (let's call it "/endpoint1" with method called "getEndpoint") with return of ResponseEntity. I set status, headers and body (body as a file, e.g. a picture). When I use my endpoint1 in browser I got a tab with correct body, a picture is shown, yet tab name (I guess this is page's title) shows "getEndpoint (XYZ)" where XYZ are pic's parameters. I tried to hardcode page title on index.html and so, yet nothing changes. Maybe I put this i wrong package or something.

Comment: Ah, that's what you're talking about. Yes, I made a mistake with the answer here. But now I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837102/looking-for-a-concise-way-to-add-title-information-to-each-page-in-spring-mvc-vi). Is this question similar to your case?

Comment: It turned out that it was enough to add Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.xyz" to HttpHeaders in ResponseEntity

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was enough to add Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.xyz" to HttpHeaders in ResponseEntity